# Are there cp2tform equivalent in tensorflow?

Tags: matlab, tensorflow, caffe

In Matlab, `cp2tform` can be used to transform key points to fixed coordinations, especially in face alignment. How to implement [`cp2tform`](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/images/ref/cp2tform.html) in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, you can check the code of a function with this:

```
>> edit cp2tform

function [trans,uv,xy,uv_dev,xy_dev] = cp2tform(varargin)
%CP2TFORM Infer spatial transformation from control point pairs.
%   CP2TFORM is not recommended. Use FITGEOTRANS instead.
%   
%   CP2TFORM takes pairs of control points and uses them to infer a
%   spatial transformation. 
%
%   TFORM = CP2TFORM(MOVINGPOINTS,FIXEDPOINTS,TRANSFORMTYPE) returns a TFORM
%   structure containing a spatial transformation. MOVINGPOINTS is an
%   M-by-2 double matrix containing the X and Y coordinates of control
%   points in the moving image you want to transform. FIXEDPOINTS is an
%   M-by-2 double matrix containing the X and Y coordinates of control
%   points in the fixed image. TRANSFORMTYPE can be 'nonreflective
%   similarity', 'similarity', 'affine', 'projective', 'polynomial',
%   'piecewise linear' or 'lwm'. See t
...
```

So you can implement it in Python or try to use one librrary for spatial trnsformations there are various specific librqaries in python:

https://github.com/kevinzakka/spatial-transformer-network

https://github.com/daviddao/spatial-transformer-tensorflow

Or one more general with spatial transformations for images:

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html